Betting Strategy Games: What's the approach
This is vague, but given four teams with implied probabilities from a bookmaker, how can you allocate $1 to win as much money as possible when betting on these teams? What if you had a model that was always right that told you: "The favorites will do  poorly" or "The underdogs will do great" (Imagine the model gave you precise new real probabilities that expressed the fact the favorites will do poorly, e.g. their real probability is halved)? How would you factor that into your betting. Intuitively, if the underdogs do great, you should bet on them. On the other hand, if the favorites do poorly, bet on everyone else. So I intuitively get the strategy. What I'm stuck on is how much to allocate to each team so that the strategy makes sense.
Like, let's say I have three teams - A,B,C - and the implied probabilities are 1/2,1/3,1/1000000 respectively and the model says the real probability for team C is more like 1/10000. How do I bet?
If someone can provide general guidelines on how to do these question that would be great.
Just some basic tips would be helpful because I really am lost, I feel like betting on team C makes sense, but also the probability team C wins is so slim, though the payout is high, like the lotto.
Of course, if the sum of the implied probabilities is less than 1, you can guarantee money because of arbitrage. But what about in scenarios where the sum of the implied probabilities is greater than or equal to 1, but you have an edge from the model telling you things?) If someone can provide an example of a sample question and model answer that would be great because I cannot find anything right now.

Your question is very broad, so my answer is going to be simultaneously broad, but it boils down to performing some kind of constrained optimisation. So you

Set up a function representing the "value" of a betting strategy (the most obvious choice is the expected payout, but more generally you'd create some kind of utility function).

Lay out the constraints for your bets - e.g. you can't bet negative money, you have some finite total bankroll, maybe there's a maximum amount you can bet on any one outcome, etc.

Find the strategy that offers the maximum value subject to your constraints.


The way to find that maximum is an entire field of study, although if your setup is simple enough there are plenty of ready-made approaches and software you can investigate.
